# Modifications to current version info in iTunes Connect not really saved

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an application in the "Prepare for Upload" state in iTunes Connect (ITC).  I had initially setup ITC with provisional information, and was ready to upload final info, such as the high resolution icon, category selection, copyright statement, etc.

ITC allowed me to make all these changes, but when I clicked the Save button and went back to the previous screen, it showed the old icon and old information.  I tried this several times with the same unsuccessful result.

I also contacted Apple's ITC support, but they sort of gave me the runaround and didn't offer any clear answer.

Comment: Note: I found an answer to this.  Due to low rep, will post it after SO's 8 hour timeout. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found a workaround.  The icon file I had been uploading was a PNG file named "iTunesArtwork" with no extension, named as you have to name it to embed it in the bundle.  On a hunch, I gave that image file a ".png" extension and updated in ITC again.  This time the update took, and I was able to submit my app with everything set up exactly as desired.

So was the file extension really the trick?  *shrug* It seemed like it to me based on the number of times I re-tried this, but it may also have been a change on Apple's side, so I can't guarantee this will work for you.